Need help making/cutting an arch
I can make everything in the picture - except the arch support.
I've reached the limit of my experience (calculating the radius, layout, bending, etc).
Any ideas would be appreciated.


Use short pieces cut ends at a shallow angle, cut many times part way though a long piece, or stream bend.  Or use something more bendable than wood.

Thank you, crip659.  Can you think of something more bendable than wood?  I like that idea.

Would Woodworking (https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/) be a better place for this?

Plastic pipe that bends has been used for greenhouses.  This looks on the small size so plastic pipe will work.  Pipe clamps screwed to the wood or the wood screwed/bolted though the pipe to hold.

If used outside you will want UV resistant plastic.

These guys: https://sciencing.com/diy-lobster-traps-5776553.html “steam their saplings”.

Could you not simply laminate two layers of "curved" wood (you could really just use straight pieces with angled butts)?

These lobster traps were steambent wood for the "arches." They've been pretty much entirely replaced with rectangular plastic-coated wire mesh. You could bend the wire mesh into an arch if you wanted to, but nobody actually does that. The illustration also lacks modern regulatory requirements for escape provisions in the event that the trap is abandoned/"lost" (aka a "ghost trap" - now have to have a part that will break down and let the trapped lobsters out after some period of time.)

@Ecnerwal  This is for a school play as a prop

@Huesmann  I think I know what you mean - to confirm - What do you mean by angled butts?

@Marinaio if you butt two pieces of regular lumber together, you end up with two straight pieces.  If you cut the ends of the pieces at an angle and butt them together, you get a "curve."  Kinda like what's in this pic: https://preview.redd.it/9y0l4v9upox81.png?width=600&format=png&auto=webp&s=a7cdca14c780e2440319058f5e91618c7f15d34b  In your case, you'd want to do two layers, and overlap so that one layer's butt joints are in the middle of the other layer's segment.
